# Is every continuous one-to-one image of the reals metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f:\mathbb R→Y$ is continuous and one-to-one.

Is $Y$ metrizable?

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $Y$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial topology $\{\varnothing, \mathbb{R}\}$, and let $f$ be the identity function.

Comment: You need to say which trivial topology? The discrete topology is metrizable (but doesn't make $f$ continuous).

Comment: The trivial topology is the indiscrete topology.

Comment: It was my understanding that the trivial topology on a set $X$ generally refers to $\{\varnothing, X\}$. In case that's not true, I'll edit my post.

Comment: @florence: +1 after your update. (@Crostul: there is a widespread bad habit of using "trivial topology" to refer exclusively to the indiscrete topology, but it is more consistent to consider the discrete topology to be trivial too.)

Comment: what is $\mathbb R$? Does it come with the usual topology, if so then the OP meant a different question that the one answered?

Comment: The $\mathbb{R}$ in the domain has the usual topology, the one in the codomain has the trivial topology.